# Parsing string of arithmetic values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, floating-point, int

How should I convert a string which contains (0, real number, float, negatives) into an array of arithmetic values.

Given the input `var str = "0 12 -3 10"`

I wish for the output `var arr = [0, 12, -3, 10];`

I have tried:

- `eval(str)`, but it skips 0s and negatives
- `parseInt(str)`, but it only accepts the first index and ignores the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string and take the values as number with mapping.

Used:

- [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a space as parameter,
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with
- [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) as callback for converting a value to a number.

```js
var string = "0 12 -3 10",
    array = string
       .split(' ')
       .map(Number);
       
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extended solution with `String.match()` function:

```js
var str = " 0 12   -3 10 -0.003    0.9  b",
    arr = str.match(/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g).map(Number);
 
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string on space to create array and map array elements as numbers

```js
 var arr = "0 12 -3 10".split(' ').map(Number);
 
 console.log(arr)
```